# Averaging over adjacency groups in a loop

Tags: matlab, function, average

I have the following code which eventually outputs a graph and a 'groups' value. The results are dependent on a random function so can provide different results every times.

```
function [t seqBeliefs] = extendedHK(n, tol, adj)
%extendedHK Summary of function goes here
%Detailed explanation goes here

beliefs = rand(n,1);
seqBeliefs = beliefs; %NxT matrix
converge = 0;
step = 0
t = step


while converge ~= 1
step = step+1;
t = [t step];
A = zeros (n,n);

for i=1:1:n
    for j=i:1:n
        if abs(beliefs(i) - beliefs(j)) < tol && adj(i,j)==1
            A(j,i)=1;
            A(i,j)=1;
        end
    end
end

beliefs = A*beliefs./ sum(A,2);
seqBeliefs = [seqBeliefs beliefs];
 if sum(abs(beliefs - seqBeliefs(:,step)))<1e-12
    converge = 1;
end
end
groups = length(uniquetol(seqBeliefs(:,step), 1e-10))
plot(t,seqBeliefs)
end
```

In command window type

```
adj=random_graph(n)
```

I usually use `n` as 100 then call `extendedHK` function with same `n` then tol value (I usually choose between 0.1 and 0.4) and 'adj'

> e.g. adj = random_graph(100)
>
> extendedHK(100, 0.2, adj)

What I now need help with is running this function say 100 times, and taking an average of how many 'groups' are formed.

Comment: You can not just remove all the question!!!!!

Comment: I tried to delete it and it wouldn't let me

Comment: Because people answered you. What you post in Stackoverflow is not just for you, we are trying to build a information database for the future. You can not just delete your question once people helped you, that is selfish. Vandalizing the question helps no one.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise that this could be helpful to other people

Comment: Actually, if any of the asnwers helped you, the rule is to accept that answer, so Other people can know which one is the one that worked for you. Also consider upvoting them if you think they are good.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to upvote unfortunately

Comment: That is OK, you will earn that privilege at soon if you keep using SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, include the parameter "groups" in your function output. to do so, try this instead of the first line of your code:

   ```
   function [t seqBeliefs groups] = extendedHK(n, tol, adj)
   ```

then save this function in a extendedHK.m file.

2. open another .m file, say console.m and write this:

   ```
   results = zeros(1,100);

   for i = 1:100
       % set n, tol and adj inputs here <=
       [~,~,out] = extendedHK(n, tol, adj);
       results(1,i) = out;
   end
   avg = mean(results)
   ```

don't forget to define "results" out of the loop. since parameters that change size every loop, will make your code slow
(suppressing unnecessary outputs with ~ added later to this reply)

Comment: `[,,out] = extendedHK(n, tol, adj);` this line seems to be causing problems, the error i'm getting is

Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: sorry my bad. replace 

        [,,out] with [dummy1,dummy2,out]

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you need the current outputs of extendedHK:[t seqBeliefs]
Anyhow, you can add "groups" to the output and then from the console

```
N=100;
groups_vec = zeros(1,N);
for i=1:N
  adj = random_graph(100);
  [~,~,groups_vec(i)] = extendedHK(100, 0.2, adj);
end
groups_avr = mean(groups_vec);
```

note that if you use this code you won't be able to "see" the graphs as they will be cleared every loop iteration. you can do one of the following (1) add "figure;" before the plot command and then you will have 100 figures. (2) add "pause" to wait for key press between each graph. (3) add "hold on" to print all graphs on the same figure.

Comment: when i run this it seems to produce all he necessary results but it looks like it gets stuck in a loop and no average is outputted?

NB
I'm not bothered on the average function actually producing a graph at the minute, just to get the average calculated is suffice!

Comment: add at the end: disp(['the average is: ',num2str(groups_avr)]);